# Can Android block background thread from outside of Application?

Tags: android

I have simple Clock class, that starts a background thread, which sleeps every second and increment time:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    while (isClockStarted) {
        try {
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
            setTime(time + 1);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

On Clock object creation time instance variable initialied with `Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() / 1000;`
Because i need a unix timestamp.

I suppose this clock thread will run as long as it's process. Can Android OS just block this thread in any case?? Assume that process is immortal and restart every rime it killed by the system.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into Android's CountDownTimer? https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html

You can tell the thread when to stop with millisInFuture. I hope this helps in your case.